# Drawing Smooth Curve

Tags: ios, swift3, uibezierpath

I have two points **left** and **right**  by adding some static  value to Y  and X is AVG of both left and right I have create 3rd point **centre**

After that I draw curve using bezier path between them And all works fine.

[image]

In above curve

Now I want to create two more points (5 Points curve).

One Between **centre**  and **left** and one between **centre** and **right** .

I **tried**  to take again **Average**  and draw 5 Point curve using

```
  func drawFivePoint(_ startPoint: CGPoint?, leftCenterPoint: CGPoint?, toControlPoint controlPoint: CGPoint?, toRightControlPoint rightPoint: CGPoint?, toEnd endPoint: CGPoint?) {

    var arrPoints = [NSValue]()
    if startPoint != nil {
        arrPoints.append(NSValue(cgPoint: startPoint!))
    }

    if leftCenterPoint != nil && !(__CGPointEqualToPoint(leftCenterPoint!, .zero)) {
        arrPoints.append(NSValue(cgPoint: leftCenterPoint!))
    }

    if controlPoint != nil {
        arrPoints.append(NSValue(cgPoint: controlPoint!))
    }

    if rightPoint != nil && !(__CGPointEqualToPoint(rightPoint!, .zero)) {
        arrPoints.append(NSValue(cgPoint: rightPoint!))
    }

    if endPoint != nil {
        arrPoints.append(NSValue(cgPoint: endPoint!))
    }

    guard  let bezierPath = UIBezierPath.interpolateCGPoints(withHermite: arrPoints, closed: false) else {
        print("path is nil")

        return
    }
    curveSize = bezierPath.bounds
    let strokeColor = UIColor.white
    if curveLayer != nil {
        curveLayer?.removeFromSuperlayer()
        curveLayer = nil
    }
    curveLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    curveLayer?.lineWidth = 1.0 / self.zoomScale
    curveLayer?.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    curveLayer?.path = bezierPath.cgPath
    curveLayer?.strokeColor = strokeColor.cgColor
    viewBase.layer.addSublayer(curveLayer!)
}
```

**WRONG RESULT**

[image]

**Question : How To Calculate Points so shape is not affect and I get 5 Points on curve**

Answer (score 0):

it is hard to say, what are you trying to achieve, but if your goal is to find points which are part of the Bezier curve which you defined in the first step, see how the Bezier curve is defined first. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve). Generally, only first and last control point of Bezier curve is also the part of the curve.

To find the point P(t) on the Bezier curve for a particular t (0..1) you can use [De Casteljau's Algorithm](https://www.cs.mtu.edu/~shene/COURSES/cs3621/NOTES/spline/Bezier/de-casteljau.html)

Try this simple snippet in your playground. I choose control points so, that x is linearly dependant on Bezier t parameter. The shape of y has the same shape as Bezier curve and is easy to see it as a graph of values in the playground

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

// point
struct Point {
    var x: Double
    var y: Double
}

// linear bezier
func linearBezier(p1: Point, p2: Point, t: Double)->Point {
    let px = p1.x + t*(p2.x - p1.x)
    let py = p1.y + t*(p2.y - p1.y)
    return Point(x: px, y: py)
}

// quadratic bezier
func quadraticBezier(p1: Point, p2: Point, p3: Point, t: Double)->Point {
    let p12 = linearBezier(p1: p1, p2: p2, t: t)
    let p23 = linearBezier(p1: p2, p2: p3, t: t)
    return linearBezier(p1: p12, p2: p23, t: t)
}

// cubic bezier
func cubicBezier(p1: Point, p2: Point, p3: Point, p4: Point, t: Double)->Point {
    let p12 = linearBezier(p1: p1, p2: p2, t: t)
    let p23 = linearBezier(p1: p2, p2: p3, t: t)
    let p34 = linearBezier(p1: p3, p2: p4, t: t)
    return quadraticBezier(p1: p12, p2: p23, p3: p34, t: t)
}

let p1 = Point(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)
let p2 = Point(x: 15.0, y: 10.0)
let p3 = Point(x: 30.0, y: 5.0)

for t in stride(from: 0.0, through: 1.0, by: 0.025) {
    let p = quadraticBezier(p1: p1, p2: p2, p3: p3, t: t)
    print(p.x, p.y)
    p.x
    p.y // see the values as a graph

}

let p4 = Point(x: 45.0, y: 10.0)

for t in stride(from: 0.0, through: 1.0, by: 0.025) {
    let p = cubicBezier(p1: p1, p2: p2, p3: p3, p4: p4, t: t)
    print(p.x, p.y)
    p.x
    p.y // see the values as a graph

}
```

One could further do it more generic

```
func bezier(controlPoints: [Point], t: Double)->[Point] {
    if controlPoints.count == 1 { return controlPoints }
    var reducedPoints: [Point] = []
    for i in 0..<(controlPoints.count - 1) {
        let p = linearBezier(p1: controlPoints[i], p2: controlPoints[i+1], t: t)
        reducedPoints.append(p)
    }
    return bezier(controlPoints: reducedPoints, t: t)
}

let points = [p1,p2,p3,p4]

for t in stride(from: 0.0, through: 1.0, by: 0.0125) {
    let p = bezier(controlPoints: points, t: t)
    p.count // it is alway 1 :-)
    p[0].x
    p[0].y
}
```

which gives you the same results. The function `bezier` could be used for 'any' number of control points. Take in the account, that the bezier function is valid only for t in the interval (0...1.0) by the definition, even though you can calculate the values in any interval.

Comment: @MikeAlter I could, but I am not sure what do you wont to do.  Do you like to find a point which is part of your Bezier curve with the position somewhere between the midpoint and the first (control point) and between the midpoint and the last (control point)? From Your question I understand, that you have defined the Bezier curve as quadratic Bezier curve, am I right?

Comment: Yes, I  have Two Points left and right , from that i have created middle point . but now i need add two more points Without Affecting Curve . So after Finding that points when I draw 5 point  curve it should as smooth as 3 points. Now you got my point ?

Comment: Ok Thanks ,   I will check and let you know is working or not